# Медленно загружается страница Bitrix CMS

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!
Народ, помогите вот с такой вот проблемой:
Главная страница [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://career.nsd.ru/) очень медленно грузится.

Особенно это заметно если во время загрузки чуть-чуть вниз проскроллить: там есть слайдер с сотрудниками. Так вот когда страница ещё не полностью загрузилась, слайдер неппроинициализирован, и вместо больших, нормальных картинок отображаются миниатюрные картинки, а этого быть не должно. Приходится ждать 4-5 секунд, когда страница полностью прогрузится, и только тогда слайдер нормально работает, и элементы корректно отображаются.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Помогите пожалуйста.

Версия Битрикс: 17.0.9, редакция Бизнес

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

> Когда браузер обрабатывает HTML-документ и встречает тег `<script>`, он
>   должен выполнить его перед тем, как продолжить строить DOM.

а у вас на странице после строки `<!--/Форма обратного звонка-->`
подгружается скрипт:
 `<script src="//common/custom.js"></script>`
браузер пытается загрузить скрипт по адресу, но безуспешно, и после таймаута продолжает строить DOM.

Вам нужно выявить где и зачем вы добавили эту ссылку, и поправить или удалить с этой страницы, и проблема уйдет.

P.S. пользуйтесь инструментами разработчика в браузере.

Comment: Этот скрипт нормально загружается, я его добавил, чтобы под Explorer страница корректно отображалась

Comment: Да, действительно, путь до скрипта был неверный, поправил - и стало гораздо быстрее подгружаться.